# How to combine a line into the upper line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Hi I have a file like this:

```
12345.jpg

mv ABCDE.JPG
```

I need to get the result of :

```
mv ABCDE.JPG 12345.jpg
```

I have researched and all solutions are about combining the upper line to the bebinning of the below line. I know how to do

```
12345.jpg mv ABCDE.JPG
```

but it is not what I need!

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi Sorry for the unclear if I made any. I know how to replace mv with /r/nmv and combine the 2 lines. But I really need the opposite order! If anyone could help?

Comment: `(.+)\R{2}(.+)` -> `$2 $1`. If the lines are separated with 1 line break, use `(.+)\R(.+)`

Comment: Oh I got it!I used replace first to make them into one line like this: 12345.jpg mv ABCDE.JPG. And then use shift+alt+arrow key to select the column and cut and paste!

Comment: Thank you Wiktor!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use regular expressions with capturing group and backreferences in the replacement.

If there are two line breaks between lines, use

```
(.+)\R{2}(.+)
```

and replace with `$2 $1`. If the lines are separated with 1 line break, use `(.+)\R(.+)` regex.

**Details**:

- `(.+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more chars other than line break chars
- `\R{2}`  - exactly 2 line breaks
- `(.+)` - Group 2 capturing one or more chars other than line break chars.

The `$1` inserts the text captured by the capturing group 1 and `$2` does the same with Group 2.

[image]